# Victory Charts - Combine more than two containers in createContainer

Tags: react-redux, victory-charts

Is it possible to combine more than two containers in createContainer, or do it some other way?

Right now, I'm using createContainer("zoom", "voronoi"), but I would to add the cursor on mouseover. The problem is that if I switch to createContainer("zoom", "cursor") I lose the tooltip I'm using when moving around the graph.

Does anyone have a solution or is it currently not feasible to do this?

Comment: I need to do this too. Did you resolve this?

Comment: I’d tried it but no way, sorry. I open a conversation in Github but nobody answer: https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory/discussions/2551